# What is dispatch_once_t

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Can someone tell me what is dispatch_once_t and it's significance.

this is what apple writes in its documentation

> A predicate for use with the dispatch_once function

which either I am unable to understand.

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static JitsiMeet *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Can someone please explain me? keeping above code as a reference?

Comment: Directly from 'dispatch_once' documentation, 'predicate' referred as 'A pointer to a dispatch_once_t structure that is used to test whether the block has completed or not.'

Comment: dispatch_once_t is typedef'd in once.h to intptr_t - and that's ultimately a long. The point is there's some piece of memory that you alloc, statically, and that's what the dispatch_once machinery uses (the fixed address of it, guaranteed unique) to determine if the block has already happened or not, in a thread-safe way.

Comment: On a side note, I **believe** (I'm still an Objective-C novice myself) that you need to use the `__block` modifier: `static __block JitsiMeet *sharedInstance;`.  Otherwise, the block being invoked in `dispatch_once` will be modifying a stack-local copy of the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for `dispatch_once` it takes a parameter `dispatch_once_t` that is used to test whether the block has completed or not.

So your code is simple to explain:

- You want to initialise `JitsiMeet` only once.
- You created a token to check wether you have initialised it or not, and named it `onceToken`
- You called `dispatch_once`, it checks the value of `dispatch_once_t`.

  - It proceeds to initialise `sharedInstance`
  - It skips to initialise `sharedInstance` the next time the `sharedInstance` function is called.
- `dispatch_once` made sure that you never return `nil`.

Comment: Is the "`init` function" is the `sharedInstance` method?

Comment: Is `init` called multiple times?

Comment: by `init` I mean, whenever you call `sharedInstance`

Comment: Yes, whenever you make an instance of a `class` the default `init` is always called first.

Comment: So the "the `init` function" is the `sharedInstance` method and not the `init` method in `[[self alloc] init]`?

Comment: Yes, "the init function" is the `sharedInstance` method and not the `init` method in `[[self alloc] init`